# App Enigne flex Java - Authenticating API using Google Cloud Endpoints JWT

Tags: java, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-flexible

We have an App Engine flex Java REST API and want it to be secured with Google Cloud Endpoints. We have successfully done this with API key,
but we want to do it with JWT.

Our consumer for API is outside of Cloud and doesn't have a Google account. In the official documentation for App Engine flex, it has examples for API key but not for JWT. We have gone through ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication)) but couldn't find anything for Java.

Comment: Did you noticed that at the end of the documentation you posted there's a link to the [Java Endpoint example in GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/endpoints/getting-started)? The [openapi.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/getting-started/openapi.yaml) has a section about JWT authentication.

Comment: @GuillermoCacheda Thanks for the review, It suggests only using API key, and while calling add it as a parameter, But not for how to generate JWT token and make a call with it. openapi.yml specifies securing API but not for calling it. I'm currently exploring other articles for the same.

Comment: @Mayur In the [official JWT docs](https://jwt.io) you'll find a myriad of client libraries to generate JWTs.